# Can a non-homogeneous equation be solved by substitution normally done in homogeneous ones?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have got a question in my material that's,

$(y+3x^2)\frac {dx}{dy}=x$

For solving it I did following,

$\frac {dy}{dx}= \frac {y}{x} + 3x$

and then substituted $y=vx$ i.e $\frac {dy}{dx} = v + x\frac {dv}{dx}$

or $v+ x\frac {dv}{dx} = v + 3x$

or $\frac {dv}{dx} = 3$

i.e $\frac {y}{x} = 3x + c$  { c is arbitrary constant }

or $y=3x^2 + cx$ and this tallies with the real answer. But my professor said that this substitution is only allowed for homogeneous differential equations and cannot be done here.
Who's Right?

Comment: I think that your solution is perfectly right. The substitution is designed for homogeneous differential equations but it can be used here, and as you said, it tallies with the real answer.

Comment: Yeah I also though so... I mean we use this kind of rule in integration, don't we? we substitute variables.

Comment: Yes. We can substitute any variables and the only consideration is --- does this simplify the question?